# Can you explain the output: diff.sort_values(ascending=False).index.astype

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone explain the following statement.

```
list(diff.sort_values(ascending=False).index.astype(int)[0:5])
```

Output: Int64Index([24, 26, 17, 2, 1], dtype='int64')

It sorts first, but what is the index doing and how do i get 24, 26, 17, 2 ,1  ??

diff is series

```
    ipdb> diff
1     0.017647
2     0.311765
3    -0.060000
4    -0.120000
5    -0.040000
6    -0.120000
7    -0.190000
8    -0.200000
9    -0.100000
10   -0.011176
11   -0.130000
12    0.008824
13   -0.060000
14   -0.090000
15   -0.060000
16    0.008824
17    0.341765
18   -0.140000
19   -0.050000
20   -0.060000
21   -0.040000
22   -0.210000
23    0.008824
24    0.585882
25   -0.060000
26    0.555882
27   -0.031176
28   -0.060000
29   -0.170000
30   -0.220000
31   -0.170000
32   -0.040000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Yout code return list of `index` values of top5 values of `Series` sorted in descending order.

First 'column' printed in pandas Series is called `index`, so your code after sorting convert values of index to integers and slice by indexing.

```
print (diff.sort_values(ascending=False))
24    0.585882
26    0.555882
17    0.341765
2     0.311765
1     0.017647
12    0.008824
23    0.008824
16    0.008824
10   -0.011176
27   -0.031176
32   -0.040000
21   -0.040000
5    -0.040000
19   -0.050000
15   -0.060000
3    -0.060000
13   -0.060000
25   -0.060000
28   -0.060000
20   -0.060000
14   -0.090000
9    -0.100000
6    -0.120000
4    -0.120000
11   -0.130000
18   -0.140000
31   -0.170000
29   -0.170000
7    -0.190000
8    -0.200000
22   -0.210000
30   -0.220000
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

---

```
print (diff.sort_values(ascending=False).index.astype(int))
Int64Index([24, 26, 17,  2,  1, 12, 23, 16, 10, 27, 32, 21,  5, 19, 15,  3, 13,
            25, 28, 20, 14,  9,  6,  4, 11, 18, 31, 29,  7,  8, 22, 30],
           dtype='int64')

print (diff.sort_values(ascending=False).index.astype(int)[0:5])
Int64Index([24, 26, 17, 2, 1], dtype='int64')

print (list(diff.sort_values(ascending=False).index.astype(int)[0:5]))
[24, 26, 17, 2, 1]
```

Comment: So i guess, i am trying to pick top 5 positive values here?

Comment: @AsifH - I think it is index of top5  values in descending order, if all values are positive depends of data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening:

- diff.sort_values(ascending) - sorts a Series. By default, ascending is True, but you've kept it false, so it returns sorted Series in descending order.
- pandas.Series.index returns a row-labels of the index (the sorted numbers 1 - 32 in your case)
- .as_type(int) typecasts index row-labels as integers.
- [0: 5] just picks the cells 0 through 5

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Oh I just read the question again - diff is a Series. my bad - updating my answer.